# Copying files between instances using gcloud compute scp

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud

I ran into a brick wall with this. I have granted both instances full access: Allow full access to all Cloud APIs.

I am using the following **command**:

```
gcloud compute scp [myinstancename]:/var/www  /var/www --recurse --zone europe-west1-d
```

or

```
gcloud compute scp root@[myinstancename]:/var/www  /var/www --recurse --zone europe-west1-d
```

Google Cloud Network Firewall has SSH enabled.

No matter what I have tried, I get the following **error**:

> Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check several things:

- Have you added/edtited ssh keys to the instance or project metadata? If so, ensure you have the correct public key file in the user's directory of your local machine:

*.ssh/google_compute_engine*

- Can you ssh to the instance using the gcloud command?

  ```
  gcloud compute ssh [instance_name]
  ```

You should have installed the gcloud sdk, the official way to install it is detailed in Google Cloud docs here:

[Installing Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/downloads)

If you never ran a gcloud command in your local machine, you need to initialize it by running:

```
gcloud init
```

- If you still can not ssh to the instance from your local machine, ensure you have the public key file in the user's directory:

It would help if you run the gcloud ssh with some debug flags:

```
gcloud compute ssh [instance_name] --log-http --verbosity debug
```

- Compute Engine API quota. Usually this shouldn't be changed but it could be that someone else by mistake limited the max requests to the API.